# asp.net mvc soap request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

i have URL like this : https://soapserver.example.com/blahblah.asmx?wsdl

i need to send some params to the this URL and get response.

1 - i created asp.net mvc project

2-  Generated Service reference - Project > Add Service Reference > Submited URL

3 - edited controller like this

```
PromoKontrol.ServiceSoapClient ProKontrol = new PromoKontrol.ServiceSoapClient();
    ProKontrol.PromosyonKoduKontrol(UserName, Password);
```

i am using breakpoint but i cant see any response?

Comment: Because you're not doing anything with the response? `var response = ProKontrol.PromosyonKoduKontrol(UserName, Password);`

Comment: my fault, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you assign the data returning from the service to some variable.

In the below code keep the debugging point and check the returnDate;

```
PromoKontrol.ServiceSoapClient ProKontrol = new PromoKontrol.ServiceSoapClient();
var returnDate = ProKontrol.PromosyonKoduKontrol(UserName, Password);
```